# How restrict textbox in C# to only receive numbers and (dot "." or comma ","), after "." or "," only allow 2 number characters

Tags: c#

i am trying develop a code to restrict TextBox using C# to only allow numbers entry + comma(",") or dot(".") + only 2 numbers after dot or comma
So this way see possible numbers that can entry:

```
3213,04 = OK
3211,664 = Not
32.31 = OK
32.3214 = Not
334,,00 = Not
3247,.00 = Not
214.,00 = Not
32.. = Not
8465,0 = Ok
654.0 = Ok
```

Understood My goal ?
I developed code bellow

```
private void txtValormetrocubico_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtValormetrocubico.TextLength >= 0 && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemPeriod || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Oemcomma))
    {
        //tests 
    }
    else
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
            && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == ','  && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about this number without any '.' or ',' is it fine or not 
123456879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is auxiliary function I have written

```
private bool alreadyExist(string _text , ref char KeyChar)
        {
            if (_text.IndexOf('.')>-1)
            {
                KeyChar = '.';
                return true;
            }
            if (_text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
            {
                KeyChar = ',';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This your key press event handler

```
 private void txtValormetrocubico_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                    && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            //check if '.' , ',' pressed
            char sepratorChar='s';
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
            {
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (txtValormetrocubico.Text.Length == 0) e.Handled = true;
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (txtValormetrocubico.SelectionStart== 0 ) e.Handled = true;
                // check if there is already exist a '.' , ','
                if (alreadyExist(txtValormetrocubico.Text , ref sepratorChar)) e.Handled = true;
                //check if '.' or ',' is in middle of a number and after it is not a number greater than 99
                if (txtValormetrocubico.SelectionStart != txtValormetrocubico.Text.Length && e.Handled ==false)
                {
                    // '.' or ',' is in the middle
                    string AfterDotString = txtValormetrocubico.Text.Substring(txtValormetrocubico.SelectionStart);
                    
                    if (AfterDotString.Length> 2)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //check if a number pressed

            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                //check if a coma or dot exist
                if (alreadyExist(txtValormetrocubico.Text ,ref sepratorChar))
                {
                    int sepratorPosition = txtValormetrocubico.Text.IndexOf(sepratorChar);
                    string afterSepratorString = txtValormetrocubico.Text.Substring(sepratorPosition + 1 );
                    if (txtValormetrocubico.SelectionStart > sepratorPosition && afterSepratorString.Length >1)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                   
                }
            }

            
        }
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, very thanks for that, will study what you did. +1 for you.

Comment: Only one doubt, i have about 10 textbox that will use this code on same windows form, will be need create copying and paste for each key press event this big code replacin textname in code ? or can i do it another way referecing this code (but i dont know how solve textname problem). Thanks again

Comment: @felipeSalomao It's probably irrelevant to you by now, you can simply name the method something generic like "TextBoxValidate" and assign it to all of your 10 textboxes' KeyPress-Events, so that all TextBoxes call the same method. The next step is to use the sender-Variable which is given to the method instead of txtValormetrocubico. You thereby would use ((TextBox)sender). It contains the appropriate TextBox so the rest of the code should work just fine over any TextBox it's assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like Masked Textbox control here you have some references

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/

Another way to do what you want is to use regular expressions

Comment: Thanks, but i dont like maskedtexbox. I prefer use custom code because it not appears "-" or $ until field filled.. i already all working, only have to solve this little problem to solve it for complete. Anyway thanks for info

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create a general function and call it on `keypress` event this code is a general instance.

`validate_textBox` is a general function

```
private void validate_textBox(TextBox _text, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                    && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            //check if '.' , ',' pressed
            char sepratorChar = 's';
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
            {
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (_text.Text.Length == 0) e.Handled = true;
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (_text.SelectionStart == 0) e.Handled = true;
                // check if there is already exist a '.' , ','
                if (alreadyExist(_text.Text, ref sepratorChar)) e.Handled = true;
                //check if '.' or ',' is in middle of a number and after it is not a number greater than 99
                if (_text.SelectionStart != _text.Text.Length && e.Handled == false)
                {
                    // '.' or ',' is in the middle
                    string AfterDotString = _text.Text.Substring(_text.SelectionStart);

                    if (AfterDotString.Length > 2)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //check if a number pressed

            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                //check if a coma or dot exist
                if (alreadyExist(_text.Text, ref sepratorChar))
                {
                    int sepratorPosition = _text.Text.IndexOf(sepratorChar);
                    string afterSepratorString = _text.Text.Substring(sepratorPosition + 1);
                    if (_text.SelectionStart > sepratorPosition && afterSepratorString.Length > 1)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can call function like this code for each textbox you have in the form

```
        private void txtValormetrocubico_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            validate_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
        }
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            validate_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks again guy. It will help me too much, on this code and in all my entire project. I not have much knowlodge on C# yet, but a lot of things that i learned was on stackoverflow. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who is looking for this in 2021 but here is one solution overriding the ontextchange event! Cheers

```
  protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
   
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        String text = "";

        Char[] chars = this.Text.ToString().ToCharArray();

        int total_dots = 0;
        int dot_pos = 0;

        int char_pos = 0;

        foreach (Char c in chars )
        {
            char_pos++;
           
            if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            {

                if(dot_pos > 0) { //dot already exists
                    
                    if (char_pos <= dot_pos + 2)  //only accept two numbers after dot (3.99)
                    {
                        text += c.ToString();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    text += c.ToString();
                }

               
            }

            if(c == '.' || c == ',')
            {
                total_dots++;

                if (char_pos > 1 && total_dots <=1)   //only accept one dot and if the dot is not in first position
                {
                    text += c.ToString();
                    dot_pos = char_pos;
                }
            }

        }

        this.Text = text;
        this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;

    }
```