# how to make textbox numbers and operators only and in a valid form . . .

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, calculator, indexof

when I am entering input like this "12312.-.-.,," program is not working or giving any error

````
            string c = textBox1.Text;
            if (c.Contains(".") || c.Contains("-") || c.Contains("1") || c.Contains("2") || c.Contains("3") || c.Contains("4") || c.Contains("5") || c.Contains("6") || c.Contains("7") || c.Contains("8") || c.Contains("9") || c.Contains("0"))
            {
                if (c.IndexOf('-') == 0 || c.IndexOf('.')==c.Length-1)
                {
                    c = c.Substring(1, c.Length - 1);
                    if (c.Contains("-") || c.Contains("."))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }


                }
            }
            else { textBox1.Clear(); }```
````

Comment: Could you, please, explain the *syntax* (what does `"12312.-.-.,,"` mean), *desired* outcome and *actual* on (what is "program is not working")?

Answer (score 0):

You really should check input values with regular expressions:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$");
string test1 = "-123.23";
string test2 = "12312.-.-.,,";
if (!rgx.IsMatch(test1)) MessageBox.Show("Error in test1");
if (!rgx.IsMatch(test2)) MessageBox.Show("Error in test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesnt enter your check for string to "not" start with '0' or end with '.' i assume?

`if (!(c.IndexOf('-') == 0 || c.IndexOf('.')==c.Length-1))`

Comment: i tried this and still  having some problems i need complete solution  :/

Comment: AFAIK this is what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050749/how-restrict-textbox-in-c-sharp-to-only-receive-numbers-and-dot-or-comma